# Typescript filter an array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to filter my `results` array based on the values stored in filters.
I have tried the below code. But it is not applying.

```
let filters = {
  name: ["Krishna", "Naveen"],
  city : ["London"]
};
results = [
{
    "name": "Krishna#Surname",
    "city": "London",
    "age": 23
},
{
    "name": "Naveen#Surname",
    "city": "London",
    "age": 23
},
{
    "name": "Krishna#Surname",
    "city": "NewYork",
    "age": 23
},
{
    "name": "Praveen#Surname",
    "city": "Washington",
    "age": 23
}
]
this.results1 = this.multiFilter(results,filters);

multiFilter(array:any=[], filters:Object) {
const filterKeys = Object.keys(filters);
return array.filter((item) => {
  return filterKeys.every(key => {
    let filters1= filters[key];
    return filters1.every(key1 => {
      return !!~ item[key].indexOf(key1)
    });
  });
});
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could check for every filter and returns that object which matches all conditions.

This approach works for an arbitrary count of conditions.

```js
function multiFilter(array, filters) {
    return array.filter(o =>
        Object.keys(filters).every(k =>
            [].concat(filters[k]).some(v => o[k].includes(v))));
}

var filters = { name: ["Krishna", "Naveen"], city: ["London"] },
    results = [{ name: "Krishna#Surname", city: "London", age: 23 }, { name: "Naveen#Surname", city: "London", age: 23 }, { name: "Krishna#Surname", city: "NewYork", age: 23 }, { name: "Praveen#Surname", city: "Washington", age: 23 }],
    filtered = multiFilter(results, filters);
  
  console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I have made a small change. My name contains #Surname but In filters I have only Krishna. How can I filter that?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to use your solution in my case. Could you take a look here?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62290308/using-filter-function-in-typescript

Answer (score 6):

An alternative is using the function `filter` along with functions `includes` and `some`.

```js
let filters = { name: ["Krishna", "Naveen"], city : ["London"]},
    results = [{    "name": "Krishna#Surname",    "city": "London",    "age": 23},{    "name": "Naveen",    "city": "London",    "age": 23},{    "name": "Krishna",    "city": "NewYork",    "age": 23},{    "name": "Praveen",    "city": "Washington",    "age": 23}],
    result = results.filter(({name, city}) => filters.name.some(n => name.includes(n)) && filters.city.includes(city));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I have made a small change. My name contains #Surname but In filters I have only Krishna. How can I filter that?

Comment: @Krishna do you want to accept that kind of names as well?

Comment: Yes @Ele. I need to filter those kind of values also

Answer (score 3):

You can `filter` the array and use `includes` to check if name and city is on the array

```js
let filters = {name: ["Krishna", "Naveen"],city: ["London"]};
let results = [{"name": "Krishna","city": "London","age": 23},{"name": "Naveen","city": "London","age": 23},{"name": "Krishna","city": "NewYork","age": 23},{"name": "Praveen","city": "Washington","age": 23}]

let result = results.filter(o => filters.name.includes(o.name) && filters.city.includes(o.city));

console.log(result);
```